# What is the proper usage of RpcMgmtEnableIdleCleanup in managed code?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, destructor, vb6-migration

I am modernizing a VB6.0 COM component to a .Net COM `ServicedComponent` I noticed that the original VB6.0 component was calling a method `RpcMgmtEnableIdleCleanup` in the `Class_Terminate` destructor.

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Call RpcMgmtEnableIdleCleanup
End Sub
```

I am unsure if I need to persist this code during the modernization, or if GC will simply handle this.

Basically, do I need this in my managed code?

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    Call RpcMgmtEnableIdleCleanup()
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub
```

I have searched and I haven't found anything specifically regarding my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like voodoo programming. One imagines you do this at the beginning of a program not the end.

It can only be turned on not off. It may be on or off as the system determines. The system will turn it on when necessary.

I'd say this is nothing to do with a program but system administration. If it solved a problem with a particular version that reason is long gone.

Here's the remarks from Help.

> Remarks
>
> Note  RpcMgmtEnableIdleCleanup is a Microsoft extension to the OSF-DCE RPC specification.
>
> Calling this function only is sufficient. Once called, idle resource cleanup cannot be turned off. In some cases, depending on Windows version and configuration, RPC Runtime may need to create a separate thread in order to perform such cleanup, which is why idle resource cleanup is not always turned on. On Windows XP and later versions of Windows, RPC Runtime is programmed to automatically turn on idle resource cleanup if idle resources reach a certain threshold.